# Submit dynamic form with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am looking to submit a page full of quantities to a page and then return their values.  I have the following:

```
<input type="number" name="item1" />
<input type="number" name="item2" />
<input type="number" name="item3" />
<input type="number" name="item4" />
<input type="number" name="item5" />
```

AJAX:

```
function getnames(){
    $.ajax({
          method: 'post','getnames.php',
          data: {
            'order': order,
            'ajax': true
          }
          success: function() {

    });
}
});
}
```

I want to find a way to post all input fields that contain the string "item" in the name so my question is:

How do I put a variety of input fields into a javascript array and then post them using ajax?

Comment: [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ajaxForm/ajaxSubmit functions from Ajax Form Plugin or the jQuery serialize function.

AjaxForm:

```
$("#theForm").ajaxForm({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})
```

or

```
$("#theForm").ajaxSubmit({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})
```

ajaxForm will send when the submit button is pressed. ajaxSubmit sends immediately.

Serialize:

```
$.get('server.php?' + $('#theForm').serialize())

$.post('server.php', $('#theForm').serialize())
```

AJAX serialization documentation is here.